# How can I replace UndirectedEdges to pairs of bi-directional DirectedEdge in a Graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

How can I have pair of edges between nodes in this kind of graphs?

```
cities = CityData[{All, #}] & /@ {"Germany"}; bigcities = 
Select[Select[Join @@ cities, FreeQ[#, ""] &], 
CityData[#, "Population"] > 100000 &];
cityCoords = 
Select[CityData[#, "Coordinates"] & /@ bigcities, FreeQ[#, ""] &];
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];
pts = Reverse[cityCoords, 2];
dt = DelaunayTriangulation[pts];
toPairs[{m_, ns_List}] := Map[{m, #} &, ns];
edges = Union[Sort /@ Flatten[toPairs /@ dt, 1]];
Graph[edges, ImagePadding -> 20, 
VertexCoordinates -> pts, VertexStyle -> LightBlue, 
VertexLabels -> bigcities[[All, 1]], 
Prolog -> {LightBrown, EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], 
CountryData["Germany", "FullPolygon"]}, ImageSize -> 800]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use DirectedGraph. At default, that will replace undirected edge to a pair of directed edges.

[image]

Comment: hamir Thanks.Now I am embarrassed!!